# datepickertime jquery/bootstrap not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm trying to get a datetimepicker, this is my refs:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/bootstrap-datetimepicker-master/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/bootstrap-datetimepicker-master/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

and this is the call:

```
                <script>
                    $("#datetime").datetimepicker({
                        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
                    });
                </script>
```

But the datepicker is shown extremely weird and no logic at all:

[image: Datetimepicker]

Seems like the css is loading correctly

[image]

Please help

Added the bootstrap-standalone-css library and then I get this atleast, but the time view toggles down on click and then immediatly back up and buttons not showing quite correct:
[image]

**UPDATE**

Seems I was missing the whole 'fonts' folder in datepicker library with a bunch of files fixing the most of it. The only issue now is that the "time-box" doesn't stay toggled up.

Comment: Seems like the datetimepicker is not using the css. Please inspect and try to find out the css class.

Comment: Looks like your CSS is interfering with the datetimepicker. Use the inspector in dev tools to debug the where the CSS is applied from and amend the selectors as needed

Comment: view page source and click on css links related to date picker whether they all are include properly or not.

Comment: It seems to show time select by default + no translation for buttons.

Comment: Worth a try - put the bootstrap.css *before* the datetimepicker css

Comment: first load bootstrap then rest all css.

Comment: i've inspected the datetimepicker and it's finding it's style classes from bootstrap datepicker css. The whole date-display is gone, I only see the time view (which is not fully correct either), I tried to reorganize my library refs but not working eitherway..

Comment: Try inspect element on your browser. And see console.log if is there's any errors. Or you can view page score and try click link your bootstrap-datetimepicker.css.  If show not found so you need check your directory. 
Edit : And my guess you need add plugin like fontawsome or something font for icon

Comment: @Wolfzmus you're right, I was missing the whole fonts folder in datepicker library, fixed the most of it, my only issue left is that the time-display box doesn't stay open when toggling it.

Answer (score 0):

change position of your libraries like below

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/bootstrap-datetimepicker-master/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/bootstrap-datetimepicker-master/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: share your full code, or you can make a fiddle and share it, so that we can inspect for the possible bug.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all of you trying to help out! I solved my timebox-toggle problem with putting it inline instead so I'm skipping the toggle completely. The main issue from the start was the missing fonts-files.